# Upload more than one HTTP PUT files using php

Tags: php, put

The following code will upload one file using http PUT Method:

```
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
```

How do i modify the above to upload two files?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, so just know that, but perhaps using a function, you can wrap your code and feed the changes into it, namely the destinations:

```
<?php

    function SaveFile($fromFile = false,$tofile = false)
        {
            if(empty($fromFile) || empty($tofile))
                return false;

            /* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
            $putdata = fopen($fromFile, "r");

            /* Open a file for writing */
            $fp = fopen($tofile, "w");

            /* Read the data 1 KB at a time
            and write to the file */
            while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
            fwrite($fp, $data);

            /* Close the streams */
            fclose($fp);
            fclose($putdata);

            return true;
        }

$files[]    =   array("get"=>"php://input1","put"=>"myputfile1.ext");
$files[]    =   array("get"=>"php://input2","put"=>"myputfile2.ext");

foreach($files as $files)
    {
        SaveFile($files['get'],$files['put']);
    }

?>
```